# Why does $u$-substitution not work here?

Tags: calculus

$$ \int{\frac{1}{2y}dy} $$

**Method 1:**

$$\int{\frac{1}{2y}dy} = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{y}dy} = \frac{1}{2}\ln|y|+C$$

**Method 2 ($u$-substitution):**

$$\int{\frac{1}{2y}dy} = \int{\frac{1}{u}dy} = \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{u}(2)dy}=  \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{u}du}=  \frac{1}{2}\ln|u|+C = \frac{1}{2}\ln|2y|+C$$

$$u=2y$$
$$du = 2 dy$$

Why is method 2 wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\ln |2y| = \ln 2 + \ln |y|$$

$$ \frac{1}{2}\ln|2y|+C = \frac 12 \ln |y| + \underbrace{\frac 12 \ln 2 + C}_{\large =\, C'}$$
So your results are equivalent up to a constant.