# Getting two different answers for $\int \frac{1}{2x} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am getting 2 different answers for $\int \frac{1}{2x} \, dx $ and I do not know which is wrong. This is the first answer with steps:
$$\int \frac{1}{2x} \, dx $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln{|x|} +C $$
This is the second answer with steps:
$$\int \frac{1}{2x} \, dx $$
$$\int1 (2x)^{-1} \, dx $$
$$u=2x $$
 $$\frac{du}{dx}=2 $$
$$\frac{du}{2}=dx $$
$$\int1 (u)^{-1} \, \frac{du}{2} $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int(u)^{-1} \, du $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln{|u|} +C $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln{|2x|} +C $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\int \frac{1}{2x} \, dx $ equal to $\frac{\ln|2x|}{2}+ C$ or $\frac{\ln|x|}{2}+ C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673822/is-int-frac12x-dx-equal-to-frac-ln2x2-c-or-frac-lnx) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2x%7D%20%5C%2C%20dx%24&p=1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820747/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780251/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2037504/42969.

Comment: $$(\log ax)'=\frac a{ax}=\frac1x$$ or $$(\log ax)'=(\log x+\log a)'=\frac1x.$$

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. Just $\ln|2x|=\ln2+\ln|x|$ and  $\frac{1}{2}\ln2$ goes in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\ln|2x|=\ln 2|x|=\ln 2+\ln |x|,$$
so they differ only by a constant.